# How to extract the unmatched column in multple file using linux

Tags: awk, grep

i have 3 files.I want all unmatched strings in all the 3 columns.I have tried

```
grep -Fvf file2 file1

awk 'NR==FNR{c[$2]++;next};c[$2] == 0' file1 file2 file3
```

But no sucess !

file 1

```
ABC  1  Town
ABC  2  Rural
ABC  3  Town
ABC  4  City
ABC  5  Urban
ABC  6  Town
```

file2

```
ABC  1  Town
ABC  2  Rural
ABC  3  City
ABC  4  City
ABC  5  Urban
ABC  6  Urban
```

file3

```
ABC  1  Town
ABC  2  Rural
ABC  3  City
ABC  4  City
ABC  5  Urban
ABC  6  Town
```

output

```
File1         File2         File3
ABC  3  Town  ABC  3  City  ABC  3  City
ABC  6  Town  ABC  6  Urban ABC  6  Town
```

Comment: Define an _unmatch_?

Comment: unmatched position means in three files for example 3rd position in column 2 in file1 is not matching to 3rd position in column 2 in file2 and file3. So this is unmatched for all the three columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a combination of `paste` and `awk`:

```
$ paste file1 file2 file3 | awk '$3!=$6 || $3!=$9'
ABC  3  Town    ABC  3  City    ABC  3  City
ABC  6  Town    ABC  6  Urban   ABC  6  Town
```

`paste` concatenates both files together (by adding columns).

`awk` is simply checking if the wanted word (the third of each file) is different, in that case `awk` prints the line.

Comment: I have 3 different files . awk '$3!=$6 || $3!=$9 || $6!=$9' will work on one file separated by space or tab

Comment: Please look at `paste` command that will aggregate both files together.